# Modify URL before page-reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an area on my site, where user can login directly with a secret link. He then is been redirected through my framework to the final view.

Now when the session dies, and the user reloads, I need to point the actual reload to the initial secret link (which the frontend knows) to get a new session and avoid the login-screen.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            // on reload: redirect to direct-login url, to ignore dead session
            window.onbeforeunload = false;
            window.location.href=$('base').attr('href') + '/users/directLogin/<?=$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['secret_token']?>';
        }
    });
</script>
```

From this code I'd expect to reload another URL when the user triggers page-refresh, but it keeps reloading the same url as is.

*To point out the problem*: If the user keeps on that final page when refreshing with a dead session, he will be thrown back to a login screen. To avoid this and give a feeling of "out-of-the-box-area" while inside the box, this concept is what I came up.

**EDIT:**
This approach is not possible. To anyone having a similar concept to achieve: A synchronous ajax would prevent the page from reloading, until the ajax finished. This way you could easily generate a session before reloading. You may consider yourself if this is a good solution for your project. It fit mines but someone might say this is evil.

Comment: You can not navigate away...

Comment: yes you are right, as I dive in I see, this is not possible. A possible workaround for this scenario would be, to throw in an non-async ajax before unload to generate a new session :)